# style component naming extending component from a ui lib

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using semantic ui react as my lib library and I'm using styled-components

I found this naming can be improved when extending (or wrapping) component from any ui lib.

```
import { Title } from 'semantic-react'

const TitleStyled from styled(Title)

..
<TitleStyle />
```

It's really hard to read, how can I use just  because most of the components in ui lib is already properly named.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this to have a better naming :

```
import { TitleSemantic as Title } from 'semantic-react'

const Title from styled(TitleSemantic)

..
<Title />
```